# Content of string is different from expected content

Tags: c++, string

the task is to read an input file, store the content of the file in a string variable and perform some operations on it. I have a problem by removing all new line characters from the string. Reading the content of the file and storing it in a string variable works fine, but somehow trying to remove the new line characters doesn't work as it should.

For reading the content of the file, I just use an ifstream. The task recommends to misuse the string datatype in order to achieve fast input and output. This is done with the following lines, where file is the ifstream variable and size is the size of the file:

```
string buffer(size, ' ');
file.read(const_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), size);
```

This works perfectly fine, but if I try to remove the new line characters, the content of buffer changes somehow, see example below. I try to remove the new line characters with the following line:

```
buffer.erase(std::remove(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '\n'), buffer.end());
```

Example:
I have a text file with the content (no new line at the end):

```
line 1
line 78
line 3
```

I want the output to be:

```
line 1line 78line 3
```

Somehow the output is:

```
line 38
```

I really have no idea, why this is happening. Printing buffer after reading the file works perfectly fine, but after trying to remove the new line characters the output is always wrong.

I hope you can help me finding a solution.

Comment: The true beauty of the [mre] is it's a distillation of a few debugging techniques which makes it  hard to write a good one without solving the problem and eliminating the need for a question. It's in your best interests to make the MRE before asking the question because you probably won't have to ask the question.

Comment: How are you opening the file?

Comment: Worth stating that: `string buffer("line 1\nline78\nline 3\n");
    buffer.erase(std::remove(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '\n'), buffer.end()); cout << buffer;` works correctly, so your buffer likely doesn't contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file has Windows newlines `\r\n`. When you remove `\n`, you get `line 1\rline 78\rline 3`. `\r` in output is treated as caret return, i.e. move next output position to the beginning of the line. Thus `line 78` rewrites `line 1` and `line 3` rewrites first 6 chars of `line 78`. You get `line 38`.

The simplest solution

```
buffer.erase(std::remove(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '\r'), buffer.end());
buffer.erase(std::remove(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '\n'), buffer.end());
```

Comment: Good diagnosis, sub-optimal solution. The “correct” solution is to open the file in text mode. That fixes the system line endings.

Comment: The "correct" solution with opening the file in text mode will not work on Linux for files originally created on Windows (downloaded for example). OP did not say about his platform.